# Extracting word with co-occurring alphabets in R

Tags: r, string

I wanted to extract certain words from a bigger word-list. One example of a desired extracted word-list is: extract all the words that contain /s/ followed by /r/. So this should give me words such as sər'ka:rəh, e:k'sa:r,  səmʋitərəɳ, and so:'ha:rd. from the bigger word-list.

Consider the data (IPA transcription) to be the one given below:

```
sər'ka:rəh
sə'lᴔ:nija:
hã:ki:
pu:'dʒa:ẽ:
e:k'sa:r
mritko:
dʒʱã:sa:
pə'hũtʃ'ne:'ʋa:le:
kərəpʈ
tʃinhirit
tʃʰəʈʈʰi:
dʱũdʱ'la:pən
səmʋitərəɳ
so:'ha:rd
məl'ʈi:spe:'ʃijliʈi:
la:'pər'ʋa:i:
upləbɡʱ
```

Thanks much!

Comment: Please add a part of the list so we can run code with, try usign the `dput` function (do `?dput` for more info)

Comment: Which of these 'words' do you want to match? You say that you only want to match "words that contain /p/ followed by /t/". To my mind there is no word in the list that meets that requirement.

Comment: Another question: when you say you want to extract words, do you mean 'extract' or do you mean 'match'? If you mean 'extract' then strictly speaking the words to be extracted need to be substrings of larger strings.

Comment: And one more: if you say yu want to "extract all the words that contain /p/ followed by /t/", do you mean 'contain ... followed by ...' or do you mean 'start with ... followed by ...'--that makes a hell of a difference. (To judge by your examples, `pet, part, put, pastor` the chars that are to *follow* can follow at any distance; they need not follow immediately, right?

Comment: Hi Ricardo and Chris. Thanks for your interest here. I am new to coding and only know the basics of R and am not familiar with coding terminology. I have updated the question with relevant examples. What I want is /s/ should be followed by /r/. /s/ need neither be at the start nor adjacent to /r/ in the string. Suppose the input has 100 words and 20 of them follow this condition then I want those 20 in my output. I think that imported data type is data-frame which is the problem for grep function. I also made a dummy data with pet, part, put, pastor and still did not get the desired output.

Comment: @Chris, I believe I mean "contain...followed by...". Both conditions should be met.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer to the issue described in the first paragraph of your post. (To my mind, the examples in the second paragraph are inconsistent with the issue described in the first para, so I'll take the liberty of ignoring them here).

You say you want to "extract all the words that contain `p` followed by `t`". The word 'extract' implies that there are other characters in the same string than those you want to match and extract. The verb 'contain' implies that the words you want to extract need not necessarily have `p` in word-initial position. Based on these premises, here's some mock data and a solution to the task:

Data:

```
x <- c("pastry is to the pastor's appetite what pot is to the pupil's")
```

Solution:

```
libary(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(x, "\\b\\w*(?<=p)\\w*t\\w*\\b"))
```

This uses word boundaries `\\b` to extract the target words from the surrounding context; it further uses positive lookbehind `(?<=...)` to assert the condition that for there to be a matching `t` there needs to be a `p` character occurring prior to the match.

The regex in more detail:

- `\\b`: the opening word boundary
- `\\w*`: zero or more alphanumeric chars (or an underscore)
- `(?<=p)`: positive lookbehind: *"if and only if you see a `p` char on
  the left..."*
- `\\w*`: zero or more alphanumeric chars (or an underscore)
- `t`: the literal character `t`
- `\\w*`: zero or more alphanumeric chars (or an underscore)
- `\\b`: the closing word boundary

Result:

```
[1] "pastry"   "pastor"   "appetite" "pot"
```

**EDIT 1**:

Now that the question has been updated, a more definitive answer is possible.

Data:

```
x <- c("sər'ka:rəh","sə'lᴔ:nija:","hã:ki:","pu:'dʒa:ẽ:","e:k'sa:r",
        "mritko:","dʒʱã:sa:","pə'hũtʃ'ne:'ʋa:le:","kərəpʈ","tʃinhirit",
        "tʃʰəʈʈʰi:","dʱũdʱ'la:pən","səmʋitərəɳ","so:'ha:rd",
        "məl'ʈi:spe:'ʃijliʈi:", "la:'pər'ʋa:i:","upləbɡʱ")
```

If you want to match (rather than extract) words that "contain /s/ followed by /r/", you can use `grep`in various ways. Here are two ways:

```
grep("s.*r", x, value = T)
```

or:

```
grep("(?<=s).*r", x, value = T, perl = T)  # with lookbehind
```

The result is the same in either case:

```
[1] "sər'ka:rəh" "e:k'sa:r"   "səmʋitərəɳ" "so:'ha:rd"
```

**EDIT 2**:

If the aim is to match words that "contain /s/ or /p/ followed by /r/ or /t/", you can use the metacharacter `|` to allow for alternatives:

```
grep("s.*r|s.*t|p.*r|p.*t", x, value = T)
# or, more succinctly:
grep("(s|p).*(r|t)", x, value = T) 
[1] "sər'ka:rəh"         "e:k'sa:r"           "pə'hũtʃ'ne:'ʋa:le:" "səmʋitərəɳ"         "so:'ha:rd"         
[6] "la:'pər'ʋa:i:"
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. This worked.  I have an additional query though: how can we cade the requirement that "contain /s/ or /p/ followed by /r/ or /t/". Both the or here are inclusive.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If this works for you please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.

Comment: Please accept and/or upvote the answer. That's the customary way to show appreciation on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` function. Assuming your list is called `list`:

```
grep("p[a-z]+t", list, value=TRUE)
```

Comment: This gave me the following unwanted result: 
named character(0)

Comment: Please post values of `CC` so i can test it. Try copying the output from `dput(CC)` in your post.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with sample data. The data is in .csv file in a single column. and I fetched the file in the project by the function read.delim(). dput(CC) gave unusually large and incomprehensible output.

Comment: Maybe its the case that nothing in this file passes the condition you said, looking to your transcription, that seems to be the case.

Comment: Yes, most probably due to data type. str(cc) gives me the output:
'data.frame': 6 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ ï..pet: Factor w/ 6 levels "gap","part","peter",..: 3 5 6 2 4 1. So, Its treating it as a data frame. Any idea how to do it now?

Comment: Is `ï..pet` the name of the column of this data frame? if yes, transform it into a vector with `list = as.character(cc$ï..pet)` and then run my code.